# Chef knife gives GSSAPI C library warning

Tags: chef-infra

Spending the day updating all of my tools:

Chef 10.16.2
Ruby 1.9.3-p327
Mac OSx Lion
XCode 4.5.2

Now every knife command produces these annoying warnings:

```
WARNING: Could not load IOV methods. Check your GSSAPI C library for an update
WARNING: Could not load AEAD methods. Check your GSSAPI C library for an update
```

Knife seems to work fine. I'm unable to find any help for finding or updating a GSSAPI C library.

Comment: Are you using knife-windows?

Comment: No, Mac OSx or Ubuntu 10 (problem exists on both).

Comment: I had this issue and I ended up just deleting all my gems and rebundling. That fixed it.

Comment: Ever solve this Mojo?

Comment: I never did. I finally went in to the gem source for my local copy of the gssapi gem and commented out the useless warnings.

Comment: It seems only happens when using knife against windows host because this exception throws from the `winRM` gem. and it should be fixed in `ridley`: https://github.com/RiotGames/ridley/pull/93

Comment: Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was too annoying for me to ignore. After much google searching I came to the same conclusion `@Mojo` did - comment out the warnings.

On OS X I'm using `homebrew` and `rbenv` - and my gems are located here:

```
~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/
```

You can use the `gem environment` command to get information about where yours are stored.

I had both `gssapi-1.0.3` and `gssapi-1.1.2` installed - the latter seems to be the most current version at the time of this posting, and it also seems to be where my errors are coming from. The file I had to change was:

```
gems/1.9.1/gems/gssapi-1.1.2/lib/gssapi/lib_gssapi.rb
```

Full path for me was:

```
~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/gssapi-1.1.2/lib/gssapi/lib_gssapi.rb
```

For the first error, comment out the warning somewhere around like `288`:

```
rescue FFI::NotFoundError => ex
  # warn "WARNING: Could not load IOV methods. Check your GSSAPI C library for an update"
end
```

For the second error, comment out the warning somewhere around like `300`:

```
rescue FFI::NotFoundError => ex
  # warn "WARNING: Could not load AEAD methods. Check your GSSAPI C library for an update"
end
```

Hopefully there will be a better solution soon because I don't really believe in modifying installed gems - but this error was a little too annoying to ignore.

Comment: I commented them out, and tried `vagrant up` in a new shell, they're still showing.

Answer (score 0):

This is coming from WinRM, and sadly there's no easy way to suppress this. Simply requiring the `winrm` gem (which is required for working on Windows) produces this error. You can safely ignore it.